# Android - sqlite in clause using values from array

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to execute a sqlite query:

```sql
select * from table_name where id in (23,343,33,55,43);
```

The values in the `in` clause need to be taken from an array of strings:

```sql
String values[] = {"23","343","33","55","43"}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js sqlite3 IN operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349199/node-js-sqlite3-in-operator)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe a simple `toString()` will mostly do the trick:

```
String values[] = {"23","343","33","55","43"};
String inClause = values.toString();

//at this point inClause will look like "[23,343,33,55,43]"
//replace the brackets with parentheses
inClause = inClause.replace("[","(");
inClause = inClause.replace("]",")");

//now inClause will look like  "(23,343,33,55,43)" so use it to construct your SELECT
String select = "select * from table_name where id in " + inClause;
```

Comment: If some of your values come from user input you are open to possible SQL injection attacks or at least crashes. You should look at the `DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)` and related functions before putting user input into sql statements.

Comment: You should be sure that none of your values contain [ or ] before doing this replace.  A better way would be to take the substring between the first and last characters and wrapping that in ( and )

Comment: What do you suggest if you have to wrap the values in quotations?