# Node.js sqlite3 IN operator

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sql-in

So I am currently trying to make a query in Node.js:

```
// friends is an array object
db.all('SELECT email ' +
       'FROM users' +
       'WHERE email in ?', friends, function(err, rows) {
           if (!err) {
```

I know that you can pass in an array of parameters for every '?' symbol, but is it possible to use the IN operator in this case? If not, should I do string concatenation or prepared statements?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
db.all('SELECT email ' +
       'FROM users' +
       'WHERE email in ( ' + friends.map(function(){ return '?' }).join(',') + ' )', 
       friends, 
       function(err, rows) {
           if (!err) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// friends is an array object
db.all(`SELECT email FROM users WHERE email in ${ friends.map(() => "?").join(",") }`,
    friends, (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {}
})
```